# Knockout async validation IE9

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

everything perfectly works in chrome but doesn't work in IE. This async call happens and callback(false) fired, but constCentreNumber still valid and no errors shown.

```
 self.costCentreNumber = ko.observable().extend({
            required: { params: true, message: utils.message.required("Cost Centre number") },
            pattern: {
                message: utils.message.format("Cost Centre number"),
                params: '^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}$'
            },
            validation: {
                async: true,
                message: utils.message.invalid("Cost Centre number"),
                validator: function (val, otherval, callback) {
                    dataSource.validate.costCode(val, self.shiftStart())
                        .always(function(result) {
                            callback(result);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very silly, chrome reads result as boolean, but IE - as a string, that why it still valid, being "false"

solution is:

```
callback(result == "true" || result === true);
```